# Lua script to extract info from wireshark .pcap traces

Tags: lua, wireshark

I want to get the frame time (relative) of the first packet that is not communicating on `sos` and `DIS` ports and ip address is not the one mentioned in the if statement. But the packet should be utilizing port 24111. However, the code below is not working for this purpose. It works, until I add `udp_port~=24111`. After that it gives me no results, which means that it doesn't go inside that conditional statement. I have tried to write the condition in multiple ways, even separating it out into a new if statement but it doesn't work. What I am doing wrong here. Thanks for suggestions in advance.
Here is the piece of code that I have at the moment

```
    local first_outpacket = 0
    local flag = 0
    function stats_first_packet()
        local udp_port
        local frame_time
        local ip_addr
        frame_time = time_relative_extractor()
        udp_port = udp_port_extractor()
        ip_addr = ip_addr_extractor()
        if ( udp_port ) then
            if (not (udp_port == 3000 or udp_port==3838 or flag==1 or ip_addr=="192.168.1.2" or udp_port~=24111)) then
                first_outpacket = frame_time
                print(frame_time)
                flag = 1
            else
                -- print("tcp_src_port already recorded")
            end
        else
            -- print("no tcp_src_port")
        end
    end
```

Comment: Can you explain the condition you are attempting to catch with that if statement?

Comment: I want to catch the first UDP packet that is not utilizing port 3000 and 3838 either as source or destination port (since that would be a DIS packet or a packet on sos port). Also it shouldn't be from a communication with IP=192.168.1.2. However, it should be on UDP port 24111. The flag variable in the if statement is just to make sure that I only get the time of the first packet, not all of the packets that fit the condition.

Comment: What is `udp_port_extractor`? What context is this script running in? Is this a dissector?

Comment: I am running it using tshark. To extract data out of .pcap file. I think it is a dissector. Though I must admit that I don't know much about Lua or scripting for Wireshark (neither the terminology). However, I have found what I did wrong. I am going to add that soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem apparently lies in the data type returned by the `extractor()` functions. In order to compare them with another value in the if statement they have to be converted into strings using `tostring()` function. 
For example:

```
if (not (tostring(udp_port) == "3000" or tostring(udp_port)=="3838" or flag==1))
```